# How to ensure correct character length is being input

Tags: excel, vba

I need to ensure that the user types in an integer with length (blank) in any cell of a certain column. If the user inputs a number that is not length (blank), the Excel freezes the user at that cell and prompts to re-enter until integer length (blank) has been inputted or cancel is hit.

I currently have most of the things I request working. However, my issue is that Excel doesn't recognize length errors until I move away from the cell and come back to it.

For example (using 3 as desired length):
If i am currently on Cell B12 and type in 15646, which is not length 3, I can still click enter and it will move to Cell B13, which I want to prevent. But if I move up to B12 again from B13, the length error is seen and Excel prompts me to input integer with correct length until its fixed.

For now, the length error is only being recognized when I come back to cell. I need it to recognize as soon as I hit enter and prevent from moving on to next cell.

```
Sub InputNum()
  row = ActiveCell.row
  col = ActiveCell.Column

  If col = 2 And ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
    Dim lotTextLen As Integer
    lotTextLen = Len(ActiveCell.Value)

    'checks to ensure the number put in is 3 characters long
    'requests an input number to be put in
    If lotTextLen <> 3 Then
      lotData = InputBox("Invalid Entry Length. Scan in Lot #")
        If Len(lotData) <> 3 Then
          'error message
          Result = MsgBox("Invalid Lot # Inputed. Must be 3 Characters. Try Again?", vbOKCancel)
          'if cancel is clicked, input number is made blank and sub is exited
          If Result <> vbOK Then
              ActiveCell.Value = ""
          'if ok is clicked to try again, recurses to beginning of code again
          Else
              InputNum
          End If
        Else
          ActiveCell.Value = lotData
        End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

InputNum is being called in the Sheet1

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B:C")) Is Nothing Then
    InputNum
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using the `SelectionChange` event?

Comment: @SJR Do I need to use this to ensure the code runs on any cell selected?

Comment: Why not use the `Change` event which is triggered when the cell is changed?

Comment: @SVJ Hmm i didnt think of using it. However, if I do that, the code would only apply to next cell after I type whatever I do in my previous cell correct. For example, right now whats happening is if I type something into A12, the code applies to whatever content in A13 and no A12. Wont SelectionChange and Change do the same thing in this case?

Comment: `Change` will use the `Target` cell that it has the change. So if you enter something into `A12` the `Target` used will be `A12` not `A13` (the now currently selected) - Try my answer and see for yourself :)

Comment: I think Tom's done the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

In the sheet object place the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        InputNum Target

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Then use this in a standard module

```
Public Sub InputNum(Target As Range)
    Dim IoTData As String
    Dim Result As String
    Dim isCancel As Boolean

    Do While Len(Target.Value2) <> 3
        IoTData = InputBox("Invalid Entry Length. Scan in Lot #")
        If Len(IoTData) = 3 Then
            Target.Value2 = IoTData
        Else
            If IoTData <> vbNullString Then
                ' error message
                Result = MsgBox("Invalid Lot # Inputed. Must be 3 Characters. Try Again?", vbOKCancel)
                If Result <> vbOK Then isCancel = True
            Else
                isCancel = True
            End If
        End If

        If isCancel Then
            Target.Value2 = vbNullString
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

By placing your code in a loop it will keep pestering the user for the right length until either they enter the right format or they press cancel in which instance the cell will be cleared of it's input.

You can also add `And IsNumeric(IoTData)` to your If statement to test that a number has been entered. 
Replace

```
If Len(IoTData) = 3 Then
```

With

```
If Len(IoTData) = 3 And IsNumeric(IoTData) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Dim add As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:C")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then

        If Len(Target.Value) <> 3 Then

            MsgBox "Invalid entry in cell with address " & add
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Activate
                'Enter more code
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:C")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then

        add = Target.Address

    End If

End Sub
```